# How to add subitems in a ListView

Tags: android

I'm trying to add subItems in my ListView.
My listView should be organized with emails for items and their institution for  the subitems, but with the following code I just added items, how can I add my subitems on it? I've tried so many things but it doesn't work.

```
        List<Login> listEmails = JsonUtil.getAllEmails(json);

        ArrayList<String> emails = new ArrayList<String>();

        ArrayList<String> institutions = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (Login loginObj : listEmails) {

            emails.add(loginObj.getEmailAndress());
        }

        for (Login loginObj : listEmails) {

            institutions.add(loginObj.getInstitution());
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, emails);

        emailListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: By subitems, do you mean something like [example A](http://docs.xamarin.com/samples/mobile-samples/TablesLists/Screenshots/Android/SimpleListItem2.png) or [example B](https://lh3.ggpht.com/__9PneCDHGgs/TJKOEOIl--I/AAAAAAAACt0/HI8ui6yN7JQ/s1600/sample_expandable_list_view_android.png)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way to do that is to create a HashMap for each item: Look the code below:

```
List<Login> listEmails = JsonUtil.getAllEmails(json);

                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(listEmails.size());

                for (Login loginObj : listEmails) {

                    HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    item.put("email", loginObj.getEmailAndress());
                    item.put("institution", loginObj.getInstitution());

                    list.add(item);
                }

                String[] from = new String[] { "email", "institution" };

                int[] to = new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 };

                int nativeLayout = android.R.layout.two_line_list_item;

                emailListView.setAdapter(new SimpleAdapter(this, list, nativeLayout , from, to));
```

Answer (score 3):

You need a custom adapter with two textviews and in its `getView()` method set the appropriate data to each of your textviews.

Also by now you are passing to your adapter only the `emails` array, you'll need a different structure to include `institutions` too.